# Using REGEXP with PDO (PHP) issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, pdo

I am having a problem with using REGEXP in my SQL query using PDO method. When I execute the statement I get nothing from the DB. I want to be protected from SQL Injections and I am just learning it.
If I do it this way( not safe way), it works:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.'vodici', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE vodicaky REGEXP '$a1' AND vodicaky REGEXP '$a2 ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $a ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $b1 ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $b '
    AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $be ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $c1 ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $c1e ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $c ' AND vodicaky 
    REGEXP ' $ce ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $d1 ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $d1e ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $d ' AND vodicaky REGEXP 
    ' $de ' AND vodicaky REGEXP ' $t'");
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->execute()){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['meno']." (".$row['id'].")<br>";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR PDO Exception thrown: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

But when I want to make it the right way I get nothing from the database. Those values in variables are inserted from user input through checkboxes. When the user does not check the box variable is empty, when is checked variable has value for ex. "D1" or "A1".

```
    $vodicak = $a1."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$a2."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$a."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$b1."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$b."'
        AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$be."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$c1."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$c1e."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$c."' AND vodicaky 
        REGEXP '".$ce."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$d1."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$d1e."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$d."' AND vodicaky REGEXP 
        '".$de."' AND vodicaky REGEXP '".$t;


try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.'vodici', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE vodicaky REGEXP :vodic");
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->execute()){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['meno']." (".$row['id'].")<br>";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'ERROR PDO Exception thrown: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

I ran out of ideas and StackOverflow threads :) Thanks

Comment: 1) You are defining a parameter placeholder in your query (`:vodic`), but you're not passing a parameter for it in `execute` (you should be getting an error for this). 2) This isn't the right way to build the query (to manually create the entire `WHERE` clause and pass it as a parameter). You should make a placeholder for every variable (`:a1`, `:be` and so on) and pass them all to the `execute` call.

Comment: So should I do it like this? -> ``` WHERE vodicaky REGEXP :a AND vodickay REGEXP :a1 ``` and so on? Thanks for your answer @El_Vanja

Comment: Yes, that would be the way. But not separately from the rest of the query (you can't insert a piece of a query as a parameter), write it all together and pass an array of parameters to `execute`.

Comment: Like this? $stmt->execute(['a' => $a, 'a1' => $a1]); Sorry I am really new and I do not quite understand all PDO stuff :/

Comment: Do you really need this long compound REGEXP filter as multiple AND? You can build single string and pass it as single parameter

Comment: What do you mean? Didn't I already do that?

Comment: @luxx I think what he's trying to say is that there is probably an easier solution than having 15 regex expressions that have to match to select your data. Perhaps if you showed what your regular expressions are and example data with expected matches this could be simplified.

Comment: A singular regular expression could do all of this.

Comment: I have never done a regular expression. As I said I am just learning right now.

Comment: @luxx that's not a problem; as I say, if you post some examples and explain what you want to do with it then maybe this could be a learning opportunity?

Comment: So I have this:`if(empty($_POST['A1'])){
        $a1 = "";
    } else {
        $a1 = '(^|,)A1(,|$)';  
    }` example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get your code working as you expect it to. However as per the comments you'd be far better off changing your expressions so that you don't need **15** of them!

```
// Define database connection parameters
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
$db_name = "name_of_database";
$db_user = "user_name";
$db_pass = "user_password";


// Create a connection to the MySQL database using PDO
$pdo = new pdo(
    "mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",
    $db_user,
    $db_pass,
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE
    ]
);


$sql   = "
    SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
        AND vodicaky REGEXP ?
    ";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// Using `?` as placeholders in the SQL means we can pass an array of parameters
// to the `execute` method and they will be applied to the query in the order they
// appear. I.e. the first value in the array is mapped to the first `?` in the SQL
$query->execute([$a1,$a2,$a,$b1,$b,$be,$c1,$c1e,$c,$ce,$d1,$d1e,$d,$de,$t]);

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "{$row["meno"]} ({$row["id"]})<br>";
}
```

Comment: It's working thanks, but when I am trying to add another variable I again get nothing from the database :/

Comment: @luxx How did you try to add another variable?

Comment: i just added behind last REGEXP this: AND [name_of_column] ?  and to the execute array added another variable

Comment: @luxx Okay, so you didn't use REGEXP in this last one? In that case you need an `=` between the `column name` and `?`

Comment: Yeah I did this too but I didn't get anything, I didn't even get any error. And when I run this query direct in my database in PHPMyAdmin I get rows displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225564/discussion-between-luxx-and-steven).